# HERE maps have expired SSL certificate for API (datalens) is there workaround for that?

Tags: here-api, heremaps

When I try to request  https://js.cit.datalens.api.here.com/latest/mapsjs-datalens.js I got expired SSL error. I am using 3.0.12.4 version of API. Is there another way to fix this issue (different CDN) or workaround around this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Data Lens product was discontinued a while ago. If you should still have access as a legacy customer, please talk to your HERE representative.